# How do you say "letting music play in a random order"?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

You know people use playlist to listen music at a particular order, what do you call the act of listening to music in a random order and letting the computer choose songs randomly?

For example:

> Instead of making a playlist off the songs I like, **I let it play
>   itself randomly**.

I am looking to replace the bolded part with a sort of idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Shuffle" is the term used.

> Instead of making a playlist, I just leave it on shuffle.

You can also use "random" much as in your example

> Instead of making a playlist, I let the songs play randomly.

Comment: Does it apply to other things than music and videos?

Comment: It particularly applies to playing cards.